# How to add navigationController controller in storyBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I have 3 view controller. my firstview controller i mean root view controller is normal view controller that not a navigationcontoller. i want my 2nd view controller as a navigationcontoller to push 3rd and 4th viewcontrollers. below image its showing exact my storybord but when i navigate its not working kindly guide me where i'm doing wrong.

this is the code i'm using for navigate to another view controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController2 *yourViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

}
```

[image]

Comment: You must connect the NavigationController to your RootViewController...

Comment: @SaravanaVijay i don't want my RootViewController as a NavigationController. i want my second view controller as NavigationController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect first view controller to navigation controller and present modally. Then connect navigation controller to table view controller. Connect the tableViewCell to the detail view and push it

[image]

Comment: Why you want to push programmatically? You need to pass any thing to view controller2 ??

Comment: You can pass the data in `prepareForSegue:` :)